# Huffman decompression using tables: maximum code length?

Tags: zlib

I know that `zlib` uses a 2-level table to look up huffman codes when decompressing a file. This has the underlying assumption that the huffman code for any symbol will not be longer tha 18 (9+9) bits... is there any mathematical reason for this assumption?

Answer (score 2):

The deflate format restricts the maximum Huffman code length to 15 bits.

Answer (score 0):

They must be limiting it in some way during compression.

For straight Huffman encoding, there is no such limit.

The pathological case is when one symbol is more common than all the remaining symbols combined, and then, for the remaining symbols, one symbol is more common than the rest combined, and so on. For byte-sized symbols, this type of  (extremely unlikely)  distribution will give a Huffman code length of 255 bits for the two least common codes.

(Calculating the minimal length of an input that has the above property is left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: does limiting block size to 64KB therefore ensure that there cannot be more than 18 bits in a huffman code?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of how zlib limits the potential code lengths.